# Catch errors of original page in content script of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm writing a chrome extension with a content script that finds a button on a web page and clicks it:

```
document.evaluate(HERE_MY_XPATH,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)
    .singleNodeValue
    .click()
```

The click on the button starts an internal process of the original page sending a HTTP request, that sometimes fails because of any errors on the server side. At the console in browser I can see a message like `POST https://www.mypage.com/any_request/ 429` and a stack trace, that caused by clicking the button.

**How can I react on that errors that happens out of my content script?**

Ways I've already tried, but without success

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    // my code
});

window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {
    // my code
};

try {
    buttonNodeIWantToClick.click();
} catch (error) {
    // my code
}
```

The content script is loaded from popup dynamically:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
        target: {tabId: id},
        files: ['scripts/content.js']
    })
```

Comment: Specify MAIN for world. [Inject with static declarations](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#static-declarative)

Comment: A safer solution is to observe requests via chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred in the background script or in the popup script.

Comment: Working in MAIN world doesn't unfortunately help. 
The idea with 'chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred' doesn't solve the question "How can I react on that errors that happens out of my content script?" (possible the answer is no way) but works fine for me. @wOxxOm please duplicate your comment as answer to mark it as solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It'd be more helpful for posterity if you add an answer with your actual code.

Comment: Unfortunately  I have to get my enthusiasm for `webRequest` back. It allows to have access to any http errors, like ERR_ABORTED, but doesnt react on Errors that you can see on the browser console caused by original page